# selenium webdriver c# strange behaviour

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Web Driver and encountered following exception while trying to click a proper element in web browser: `Unable to locate element`.
XPaths are 100% correct.
The strange thing is it is working ok when:

- In debug mode.
- After clicking `Continue` in VS when exception appears.
- When i am moving mouse manually on the screen.

I would be grateful for any help.

EDIT: Thread.Sleep doesnt help. I am trying to click decrease Year button in web calendar. It works first time, but freezes the second time. But the object is still there. So i dont understand how it can be not visible.

Comment: How long are you allowing the thread to sleep?  In my experience, I had not given the thread a long enough time to sleep before the page rendered, even when I thought I had.

Comment: 1,5 seconds. The strangest thing is that it click first time and it is ok. THen i needs to click the same object one more time and the problem occurs. When i move my mouse it works :D

Answer (score 1):

The driver is trying to locate the element before it loaded. Try waiting for it before clicking.

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(path))).Click();
```

Comment: Can i add some automatic mouse movement if manuall movement helps?

Comment: Something like `Actions.MoveToElement()`?

Comment: i mean to visible see moving mouse with webdriver. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try:

1-try a selector by ID instead of the xpath. Maybe new elements are being rendered and making the xpath didn't find the element.

2-implement a retry pattern

3-use thread sleep to let the page being full rendered.